# Subsection formatting in Memoir class (not bold)

Tags: memoir

In the following code, I would like to have the subsection in normal font (not bold).

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

Which command can I use?

Comment: Use `\setsubsecheadstyle{<defs>}`, where <defs> does not include `\bfseries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the the default

```
  \setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\memRTLraggedright}
```

the commands used inside it should be mostly self explanatory. The `\memRTL...` is usually just an alias for `\raggedright`